# Unable to import project from repository by URL (SSH)

Tags: gitlab

I am checking out GitLab and the first thing I want to do is to import the repository.

To do that, I am doing the following:

1. Create a project -> Import project -> Repository by URL:
2. URL: git.xyz.se:project.git

It shows the following info:

```
Import url is blocked: Only allowed schemes are http, https, git
```

How can I import project via SSH to GitLab (this is the only access)?

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar case with [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 26845](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/26845)

> You need to go to the admin panel and enable your instance to allow fetch local resources.
> This is by default disabled to prevent security risk.
>
> Admin -> Settings -> Network -> Outbound Requests -> Allow requests to the local network from hooks and services

There is a request for that setting to be enabled by default ([issue 45134](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/45134)), but that is not the case for now.

The `outbound_requests_whitelist` setting mentioned in [MR 21377](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/21377) for [issue 44496](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/44496) (Outbound requests whitelist for local networks) could help too.

Answer (score -1):

If you take a look at your repo in gitlab, on the first tab files -> on the upper right, there should be a button with clone - here you should get the url for cloning your repo.

Comment: the problem is that I do not have the repo in GitLab at all, this is a fresh instance of GitLab installed and I want to import it to here.

Comment: I edited the question, the error is now different, simply GitLab does not allow me to import SSH project, how can I achieve that?